# Unrecognized variable after a pipe with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, forcats

I am using the `gapminder` dataset for making an interactive barplot with `plotly` library. I want to reorder the levels in continent variable using `forcats` library but it does not recognize this variable when I put it after the pipe. This is the script I am using:

```
gapminder %>%
        filter(year==2002) %>%
        mutate(continent=fct_reorder(continent, pop, .desc=T))
```

I would like to know why the variable "continent" does not pass through the pipe. Thanks.

Comment: Piping doesn't change your original dataset. You have to assign it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in order to save your pipe operations on `gapminder`:

```
gapminder %>%
        filter(year==2002) %>%
        mutate(continent=fct_reorder(continent, pop, .desc=T)) -> gapminder
```